# How to generate random user id and fill with in a text box using Selenium and java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, random, webdriver

I am using an application where every time, I need to create a new users. I want code that can generate the same for me through regular expression. Example- **Alen001**, **Alen002**, **Alen003** and so on.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("userId")).sendKeys("Alen001");
```

Comment: You want to choose random username from an array?

Comment: Please tag the question with the programming language you are using. Selenium has many different language bindings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: Randomly generate distinct names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025651/java-randomly-generate-distinct-names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new random userid e.g. **Alen001**, **Alen002**, **Alen003** etc, and pass it through `sendKeys()` you can use the following line of code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("userId")).sendKeys("Alen00"+ Integer.toString(((new Random().nextInt(10))+1)));
```